# How do I get the response headers in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-rc

How can I get request/response logs in selenium? I have an ajax call that returns login information, and whenever I try to capture it via:

```
 selenium.captureNetworkTraffic("json");
```

it returns only client-side items (like images .pn), but not the actual JSON response I'm interested in.

Comment: can any one help me,i thought selenium should obviously have clicks made inside and response from it?? didnt any one tried this??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can do that with selenium alone in an automated fashion, as this is [against their design principles for selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141).  I don't agree that it is (since it supports getting cookie information -- what user actually goes through and parses through their cookies?).

Their 'schtick' is that selenium helps you automate what a user does; since a user doesn't care about the response headers, why would this framework?  For me, this is disappointing because I need to ensure the content type being returned is what I believe it should be (to test an API). It appears [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450614/selenium-2-detect-content-type-of-link-destinations) has come to a similar conclusion.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone is still looking for an answer, there is a way to get the response headers using Selenium 4 and Chrome developer tools API

```
DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();
devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(),
        responseReceived -> {
            Headers headers = responseReceived.getResponse().getHeaders();
            if (!headers.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Headers:");
                headers.forEach((key,value) -> {
                    System.out.println("    " + key + "="+ value);
                });
            }
        });
```

This was tested using Selenium 4 alpha 6

Comment: Not _just_ `ChromeDriver`...  Technically any of the drivers implementing `HasDevTools` (which appears to at least include firefox and edge).

Comment: oh petassakes, add the corresponding imports !!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this question is old as hell, but I've developed a way to do this for firefox + selenium by modifying webdriver.xpi and creating driver.http_logger.variousLogMethods(). Please reply to this post if there's interest in this, and I can post the code to github.

Comment: I am interested. Please post the github link.

Comment: @user2426679 I'm interested as well, could you please show me on Github how to execute this?

Comment: @David542 -- I finally got around to uploading this little project.  I did this a while back, so the documentation is sparse.  https://bitbucket.org/stbrownlow/seleniumwithfirefoxhttplogging/src

Comment: Interesting.  Has anyone been able to get this to work on newer versions of FF?

Comment: @FlyingZebra1 it won't work without rewriting the patch within `webdriver.xpi`. See the readme in the BitBucket for locating the edits I made to the .xpi selenium extension, as a starting point for porting to a newer version of Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for other way round solution it could be also done using proxy server which will output log file including headers for each request/response which go through the proxy.

I have used [Titanium Web Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy) and registered proxy for driver options like this:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
{
    Proxy = new Proxy
    {
        Kind = ProxyKind.Manual,
        HttpProxy = "localhost:8888"
    }
};
```

Comment: I upvoted, I did not check whether it actually works. But I think the idea is worth a vote nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by injecting a XMLHttpRequest and waiting for the result:

```
Object response = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
       "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
       "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
       "xhr.open('GET', '/resource/data.json', true);" +
       "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
       "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {" +
       "    callback(xhr.getResponseHeader());" +
       "  }" +
       "};" +
       "xhr.send();");
   JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse((String) response);
   assertEquals("cheese", json.get("food").getAsString());
```

You can modify the xhr callback to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick if you use jquery you can register a global listener :

First you need to declare a global variable in your main script :

```
var globalVariableForSelenium = "";
```

In your selenium you register the listener :

```
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {  globalVariableForSelenium = settings.headers    });");
            }
```

Then you execute your action

Finaly you get the value of the global variable :

```
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            Object res = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return  serializeGlobalvariable();");

}
```

serializeGlobalvariable() is a function that will serialize globalVariableForSelenium which contains an array of header.

ps: my need was to access to the ajax response so I set the global variable with xhr.responseJSON.mypath