# Detect link content type with PHP

Tags: php, content-type

How can I detect the content type of a link?

Users can upload links into thee web. And I'd need to save the link type (a video, a image...) in the DB (mysql).

I've found one answer (using the HTTP HEAD) with Java:
[Selenium 2: Detect content type of link destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450614/selenium-2-detect-content-type-of-link-destinations)
. However I'm using PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That solution applies, in the abstract, to PHP as well.

The way you detect a link target's content type is by performing an HTTP HEAD request (such as with the curl extension for PHP, or the `get_headers` function) and then reading the returned `Content-Type` header.

Make sure to fail gracefully if the remote end is inaccessible.

Comment: note that `get_headers` will do a GET request unless you change the method via a custom stream context

Answer (score 2):

Googling a little found me this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

You then can read the "content-type" header entry.

Comment: note that `get_headers` will do a GET request unless you change the method via a custom stream context

Answer (score 1):

[`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) - and check for Content-type header.

Comment: note that `get_headers` will do a GET request unless you change the method via a custom stream context